# Quick Tangent Line Question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I came across this really confusing tangent line question.

Given the following prompt: "Let $f$ be an increasing function with $f(0)=3$. The derivative of $f$ is given by $f'(x)=\cos(\pi  x)+x^4+6$. Write an equation for the line tangent to the graph of $y=(f(x))^2$ at $x=0$."

I've been trying to work through this and I just can't find a solution; I've tried finding the derivative of $(f(x))^2$ and evaluating that derivative at $0$, but no matter how I attack it I always get an answer of $0$ when the derivative is evaluated at $0$. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you solve it with $f'(0)=\cos(0)+6=7$ and $\dfrac d{dx} (f(x))^2=2f(x)f'(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when $x = 0$, $y = (f(0))^2 = 9$.  Then,

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (f(x))^2  \\
    &= 2 f(x) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} f(x)  \\
    &= 2 f(x) f'(x)
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*}
\left. \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \right|_{x = 0} &= 2 f(0) f'(0)  \\
    &= 2 \cdot 3 \cdot (\cos(\pi \cdot 0) + 0^4+6)  \\
    &= 6 \cdot 7  \\
    &= 42  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Then an equation of the line is $y - 9 = 42(x-0)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

$f'(0)=\cos(0)+6=7$

$\dfrac d{dx} (f(x))^2=2f(x)f'(x)$